# converting json dataset into a flowchart in VUEjs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, flowchart

in my project I'm trying to import a JSON file (which is exported from a flowchart drawing project) and convert it's data into the same flowchart. so far i didn't find any clue about how to convert JSON data to shapes in vue. please help me :D

i tried reading data in my vue project and i did it but i cant convert them into shapes.
`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{graphVar.elements}}</h1>
  </div>    
</template>

<script>
import graph from './../../graph.json'
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    data: () => ({
      graphVar: graph,
  }),
  created() {
      console.log(this.graphVar.elements)
    }
  }
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

i guess whether you want to beauty you json string?
if right, you can use the package of "[json-stringify-pretty-compact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-pretty-compact)"